# Dimension of linear compositions of polynomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $P_1\dots P_s$ be s given polynomials in $n$ variables of degree $d$. The set of polynomials $\sum_k Q_k P_k$ defines a vector space, where $Q_k$ are polynomials with degree not greater than $d_k$. What is the dimension of this space for general polynomials $P_k$?

Comment: Have you tried some computer experiments? Seems like that should be doable.

Comment: Do you fixed the $d_k$'s *a priori*?

Comment: Yes, d_k are fixed

Comment: Since the dimension of the space of theses $(Q_k)_{1\le k\le s}$ is given, it is equivalent to ask for the dimension of the kernel of the linear map $(Q_k)_{1\le k\le s}\mapsto\sum_{k=1}^s Q_kP_k$, which seems to be an algebraic object depending on the $(P_k)$ not in a simple way.

Comment: There are some special cases for with it is possible to compute the dimension in simple way. For example, this is the case when the degrees satisfy the Macaulay conditions in the definition of the Macaulay resultant